# Unable to connect to host from docker container

Tags: docker, networking

I am having trouble accessing my host machine from a docker container, getting Connection refused error. I tried to solve it following this SO question: [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Docker version is **20.10.18, build b40c2f6**
Host is Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

What I am doing:

- Started a server on port 3000 on the host machine
- server is accessible with `curl localhost:3000`

Then I tried the following, using curl docker image for testing, all throwing Connection refused error

```bash
# using host.docker.internal
docker run --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway --rm curlimages/curl:7.85.0 host.docker.internal:3000
# using IP from docker0 network 172.17.0.1
docker run --rm curlimages/curl:7.85.0 172.17.0.1:3000
# using host network
docker run --network=host --rm curlimages/curl:7.85.0 localhost:3000
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

My issue was running docker on rootless mode. https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/

After returning to the default context with

```bash
 docker context use default
```

all the above solutions worked!

Comment: Thanks, that put me in the right track. Rootless mode does not support `network="host"`!